# mongoose full collection scan

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mapreduce, mongoose

I want to scan a whole mongo collection and compute a `custom` aggregation. I am using Node with mongoose. For scanning the whole table I was using `MyModel.find({}, callback);`

When I run the code, I found mongoose executes the query and gathers the desired records in an array and then simply pass that whole array to the callback. Now in a full collection scan it takes huge time.

Isn't it possibly that I get a cursor object from which I can iterate continuously mapping desired records to some callback instead of waiting for a whole lot to be gathered in array. (this is what I observed, please correct if I am wrong).

Also, can someone please advice whether doing a full collection scan for custom aggregations is the right way or not or should I look into `map-reduce` or some alternative like that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your first option should be to use the [`aggregate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.aggregate) method instead of `find` to do whatever aggregation you're looking to do.  If that doesn't do what you need, look into [`mapReduce`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.mapReduce), like you mentioned.

However, if you find that you do need to iterate over a large collection, you should use Mongoose's support for [streaming](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#querystream_QueryStream) the result of the query rather than getting it in one big array.

```
var stream = MyModel.find().stream();

stream.on('data', function (doc) {
  // do something with the mongoose document
}).on('error', function (err) {
  // handle the error
}).on('close', function () {
  // the stream is closed
});
```

Comment: I couldn't use aggregation framework, I need not exactly group by type functionality. Very `custom` processing over records. Also I think map-reduce won't benifit me either since i would be running only one mongod instance. Streaming seems to be the thing of interest. Thanks mate :)